# Wamp Server como enviar um email usando uma conta do gmail usando um php no localhost?

Tags: wamp

Pessoal estou tendo um problema para enviar um email com código de validação de cadastro de usuário a partir do meu localhost. No meu localhost eu tenho o Wamp Server instalado configurado pra usar a porta 80, eu redirecionei todos os acessos externos ao IP do meu host para a porta 80 dessa forma é possível acessar o servidor externamente para acesso ao banco de dados etc... Fiz varias pesquisas na internet de como fazer isso achei tutoriais usando o Sendmail que não deu em nada nem se quer um erro apenas dizia que foi enviado o email, mas ao verificar na caixa de entrada do email nada.  Achei PHPMailer que ao menos apresentou um erro que foi:

SERVER -> CLIENT: 
SMTP NOTICE: EOF caught while checking if connected
Erro do SMTP: Não foi possível realizar a autenticação.
SMTP Connect() falhou. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
Erro: SMTP Connect() falhou. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

OBS: Fiz tudo que os tutoriais diziam inclusive tentei usar até mesmo um exemplo para gmail que vem junto com a classe quando vc baixa no Github. Alguém poderia me dar uma solução ou alternativa que não seja paga? Abaixo meu código php:

```
<?php
require 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->setLanguage('pt');
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';

$host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$username = 'meuemail@gmail.com';
$password = 'minha_senha';
$port = 465;
$secure = 'ssl';

$from = $username;
$fromName = 'Meu Nome Completo';

$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Host = $host;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = $username;
$mail->Password = $password;
$mail->Port = $port;
$mail->SMTPSecure = $secure;

$mail->From = $from;
$mail->FromName = $fromName;
$mail->addReplyTo($from, $fromName);

$mail->addAddress('destinatario@qualquer_dominio.com', 'Nome do Destinatario');

$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->CharSet = 'utf-8';
$mail->WordWrap = 50;

$mail->Subjet = 'Testando phpmail';
$mail->Body = 'Enviando emails com <b>PHPMailer</b> para <h2>TESTE</h2>';
$mail->AltBody = 'Enviando emails com PHPMailer para TESTE';

$send = $mail->Send();

if($send) {
    echo 'E-mail enviado com sucesso!';
} else {
    echo 'Erro: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}

?>
```

Comment: O erro está na autenticação. Tentou na porta 587? A ordem do TLS é um pouco diferente na 587. Mais um detalhe: hoje em dia você não consegue usar contas do google via SMTP com usuário e senha, precisa usar usuário + token (SASL) no lugar, a nao ser que esteja habilitada a opção de permitir "aplicativos menos seguros" na conta. Melhor verificar isto também.

Comment: Oi tentei de todas as maneiras possíveis pela porta 587 aparece mais erros ainda a opção que menos deu erro foi a 465 usando ssl. Em relação ao conta do google eu habilitei tudo que achei nas minhas pesquisas inclusive o acesso por app menos seguros.

Answer (score 1):

Seu código funcionou aqui no meu teste, a única coisa que mudei foi a forma de fazer o include da classe PHPMailerAutoload.php.

```
require './PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
```

Considerando que o diretório PHPMailer está no mesmo diretório do meu arquivo.php.

Recomendo que você utilize um debug para detectar erros, fica mais simples de entender onde está o problema, para isso você pode usar o Debug de uma IDE, como [**Netbeans**](https://www.devside.net/wamp-server/configure-netbeans-8-with-xdebug-connection-on-wamp) por exemplo. Recomendo o editor **[Atom](https://atom.io/)**, e o [**plugin de debug do PHP**](https://atom.io/packages/php-debug), no meu caso foi o que melhor funcionou.

Comment: Acho que deve ter a ver com a qualidade da conexão com internet pq eu usei um debug melhor e me retornou isso:                                                                                      Connection: opening to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465, timeout=300, options=array ()
Connection: opened
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is ""
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is ""
SERVER -> CLIENT: 
SMTP NOTICE: EOF caught while checking if connected
Connection: closed
Erro do SMTP: Não foi possível realizar a autenticação.
SMTP Connect() falhou. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting.